# Access javascript Array in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dynamic

I am creating a mobile app. I have a javascript file language.js having the following code

```
var lang=new Array(); 
lang[0]="English";      
lang[1]="Chinese";
lang[2]="Korean";
```

I want to create checkbox input based on the array in html like :

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
<input type="checkbox" name="English" value="0" onclick="setvalue(this.value)">English<br><input type="checkbox" name="Chinese" value="1" onclick="setvalue(this.value)">Chinese<br><input type="checkbox" name="Korean" value="2" onclick="setvalue(this.value)">Korean</div>
```

How do i insert the array from language.js in HTML?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a solution like jQuery templates?  They're ideal for dynamic construction of html from javascript-defined data.  Seriously, they've rocked my world.  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-an-introduction-to-jquery-templating/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd probably want something like this:

```
function buildLanguages() {
    var div = document.getElementById("langDiv");

    var html = "";
    for (var i=0;i<lang.length;i++) {
        html += "<input type='checkbox' name='" + lang[i] + "' value='" + i + "' onClick=\"setValue(this.value);\">" + lang[i] + "<br>";
    }

    div.innerHTML = html;
}
```

And your html:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label" id="langDiv">
</div>
```

A Fiddle for the Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/4qb9Y/